# Filter Data Using Session Id

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, session

I want to filter data using session id. Have a table like below.

```
id   | user_id | plan
  1  | 1       |.sjhsjh.jpg
  2  | 2       |bchdj.jpg
```

I want to filter that database value according to the login user.user id, which is the foreign key of user table. I have filter it before,but now its not working.

**model**

```
function get_plan(){

$this->db->select("floor_plan.id,floor_plan.image"); 
$this->db->where("user_id",$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']); 
$this->db->from('floor_plan');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

**Session**

```
<?php
if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {
$firstname = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['firstname']);
$email = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['email']);
$id = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']);
} else {
header("location: login");
}
```

Comment: this is a wrong way you are accessing session data. Use `$this->session->userdata('firstname')` instead of `$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['firstname']` After that post error message you are getting

Comment: Also, accessing session in the model is a bad practice. Try adding a parameter to your `get_plan()` function and send the id from the controller (using the session).

Comment: but my problen doesn't slow

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Can you put `var_dump($this->session); exit()` in your model method and post the output?

Comment: no . no any error message. ok sure

Comment: it dosen't show any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change model as following.

```
    function get_plan(){
       $userdata=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
       $this->db->select("floor_plan.id,floor_plan.image"); 
         $this->db->where("user_id",$userdata['id']); 
        $this->db->from('floor_plan');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();

       }
```

session change as following.

```
     <?php
     if (isset($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))) {
       $userdata=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $firstname = $userdata['firstname'];
     $email = $userdata['email'];
    $id = $userdata['id'];
   } else {
    redirect("login/index");
    }
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in C:\xampp\htdocs\RCJconstructions\application\views\user_include\header.php on line 29

Comment: if (NULL !==($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))) {
     $userdata=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $firstname = $userdata['firstname'];
     $email = $userdata['email'];
    $id = $userdata['id'];
   } else {
    redirect("login/index");
    }

then my views display no result found.but in database there is a value under this user id

Comment: <?php if($post) { ?> 
<?php foreach($post as $post){?> 
<tr> 
<td><?php echo $post->id ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;';?></td> 
<!--<td><?php echo $post->image ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;'?></td>-->
         <td><?php echo "<img src='" . base_url().$post->image."' width=150px; height=100px;>";?></td></td> 
</tr> 
<?php } 
} else {
    
    ?> 
<tr><td clospan="4" align="center">No records found to display</td></tr> 

 
<?php } ?>

Comment: @ashik where you call model function in controller?.

Comment: public function index(){  
        
 $data['post'] = $this->floor_model->get_plan(); // calling Post model method getPosts() 
        $this->load->view('user_include/header');
        $this->load->view('plan/floor',$data);
 }

Comment: please update your controller according to that and url.

Comment: update your code in question with controller that should complete code then I can check and modify it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87747/discussion-between-ashik-and-shanusingh).